# how to send string from ChildFrame to ParentFrame and repaint ParentFrame?

Tags: java, swing, awt

ParentFrame shows ArrayList and one "ADD" Button. Once I click "ADD" Button on ParentFrame, then ChildFrame shows up.
On ChildFrame, I type in a String and click "OK" Button then it should transfer its String to ParentFrame. Finally ParentFrame should be repainted with newly added String.

I'm having trouble with repainting but also I might failed to send String from Child to Parent since Parent didn't get repainted.

I tried several things in two or three other points of view but following code seems like to work but......

I need your help!!

1. ParentFrame

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.awt.*;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class parentFrame extends JFrame {
    ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<>(){{add("test1"); add("test2");}};
    JButton add;
    JPanel big, small;
    JLabel content;
    childFrame addFrame;
    
    public parentFrame() {
        super("parent frame");
        super.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        super.setSize(600,600);
        
        big = new JPanel();
        
        for(int i=0; i<list.size(); i++) {
            content = new JLabel();
            content.setText(list.get(i));
            big.add(content);
        }
        super.add(big, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        
        add = new JButton("ADD");
        add.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                addFrame = new childFrame();
                
                /* By next 3 lines, I'm trying to transfer the value of childFrame's test to this parentFrame's list. */
                list.add(addFrame.getTestString());
                big.revalidate();
                big.repaint();
            }
        });
        super.add(add, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        
        setVisible(true);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new parentFrame();
    }
    
}
```

2.ChildFrame

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class childFrame extends JFrame {
    String test;
    JTextField name;
    JButton ok, cancel;
    
    public childFrame() {
        super("child frame");
        super.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        super.setSize(400,200);
        
        JPanel centerPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(1,1));
        centerPanel.setSize(150, 100);
        name = new JTextField();
        centerPanel.add(name);
        
        
        JPanel bottomPanel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout());
        ok = new JButton("OK");
        ok.addActionListener(new OKListener());
        super.add(ok);
        
        cancel = new JButton("CANCEL");
        cancel.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                dispose();
            }
        });
        bottomPanel.add(cancel);
        bottomPanel.add(ok);
        
        super.add(centerPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        super.add(bottomPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        
        setVisible(true);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }
    
    class OKListener implements ActionListener {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            test = name.getText();
            dispose();
        }
    }
    
    public String getTestString() {
        return test;
    }
}
```

Comment: 1) Don't extend components and windows (like `JFrame`) unless overriding the methods they off. 2) See [The Use of Multiple JFrames, Good/Bad Practice?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9554636/418556) 3) If things are working correctly, it should not be necessary to call `repaint()` on standard Swing components. Just change the model or content, and the rest will happen automatically.

Comment: Please note charges made to my answer. If any questions about it, please ask

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is here:

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    addFrame = new childFrame();
    
    list.add(addFrame.getTestString());
    big.revalidate();
    big.repaint();
}
```

Since your child frame is not a *modal* window (for example, a JOptionPane is a modal dialog window), it does not halt program flow in the calling window.  You call `.getTestString()` immediately on creation of the child frame but ***before*** the user has had any chance to enter in any data (again, because program flow in the calling window is not halted).

The solution is to make your child "frame" in fact a *modal* JDialog. This will pretty much solve the whole issue. So, don't have the child frame extend from JFrame, but rather extend JDialog, and use the JDialog constructor that makes it *modal* (see the JDialog API).

e.g.,

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")

// note that class names should begin with an upper-case letter
public class ChildFrame extends JDialog {
    String test;
    JTextField name;
    JButton ok, cancel;
    
    public ChildFrame(JFrame parentFrame) {

        // the true parameter makes this modal
        super(parentFrame, "child frame", true);
```

Now this dialog window will freeze program flow from the calling code as soon as the dialog is set visible, and the calling code flow won't resume until this dialog is no longer visible.

Also, please have a look at [The Use of Multiple JFrames, Good/Bad Practice?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9554636)

---

An alternative to this is to continue to use multiple JFrames (not recommended!!), and add a WindowListener to the "child" window, listening for windows closing events, and then getting the information from your dialog in call-back method that is activated when the windows closing event occurs.

---

For a working example:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Window;
import java.awt.Dialog.ModalityType;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class ParentGuiPanel extends JPanel {
    private DefaultListModel<String> listModel = new DefaultListModel<>();
    private JList<String> jList = new JList<>(listModel);
    private JButton addButton = new JButton("Add");
    private JDialog childDialog;
    private ChildGuiPanel childPanel = new ChildGuiPanel();
    
    public ParentGuiPanel() {
        listModel.addElement("Test 1");
        listModel.addElement("Test 2");

        jList.setPrototypeCellValue("ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ");
        jList.setVisibleRowCount(8);
        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(jList);
        scrollPane.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
        
        addButton.addActionListener(e -> addActionPerformed(e));
        addButton.setMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_A);
        JPanel buttonPanel = new JPanel();
        buttonPanel.add(addButton);
        
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        add(scrollPane);
        add(buttonPanel, BorderLayout.PAGE_END);
    }
    
    private void addActionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        Window window = null;
        if (childDialog == null) {
            window = SwingUtilities.getWindowAncestor(this);
            if (window == null) {
                return;
            }
            
            childDialog = new JDialog(window, "Child GUI", ModalityType.APPLICATION_MODAL);
            childDialog.add(childPanel);
            childDialog.pack();
            childDialog.setLocationRelativeTo(window);
        }
        
        if (childDialog != null) {
            childDialog.setVisible(true);
            
            String text = childPanel.getText();
            if (!text.trim().isEmpty()) {
                listModel.addElement(text);
            }
        }
    }
    
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> {
            JFrame mainGui = new JFrame("Main GUI");
            mainGui.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            
            ParentGuiPanel mainPanel = new ParentGuiPanel();
            mainGui.add(mainPanel);
            mainGui.pack();
            mainGui.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
            mainGui.setVisible(true);
        });
    }
}
```

```
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
class ChildGuiPanel extends JPanel {
    private JTextField textField = new JTextField(15);
    private JButton okButton = new JButton("OK");
    private JButton cancelButton = new JButton("Cancel");
    
    public ChildGuiPanel() {
        okButton.addActionListener(e -> okActionPerformed(e));
        cancelButton.addActionListener(e -> cancelActionPerformed(e));
        textField.addActionListener(e -> okActionPerformed(e));
        okButton.setMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_O);
        cancelButton.setMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_C);
        
        add(new JLabel("Text: "));
        add(textField);
        add(okButton);
        add(cancelButton);
    }
    
    public String getText() {
        return textField.getText();
    }
    
    private void disposeWindow() {
        textField.selectAll();
        Window window = SwingUtilities.getWindowAncestor(this);
        if (window != null) {
            window.dispose();
        }
    }
    
    private void okActionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        disposeWindow();
    }
    
    private void cancelActionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        textField.setText("");
        disposeWindow();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much!! I'm trying to use both of them as JFrame... though you don't recommend this I appreciate you put it on last :)

Comment: @flash again, don't use them as both JFrames as that is one source of your problems